# An occasional bug occurred in the packaged exe of Electron on Win7. Using vtkjs to load the model initialization failed

Tags: javascript, vtk

I used vtkjs to render stl models in the project, but sometimes there were model loading failures on Win7. The project was opened using electronic quick start, and there were no issues on the web side. However, when using exe to render, there were problems and errors

`TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non object as tainget or handler

At object L. T. get3DContext (vendor. a7ff823.15:37)

At Object L. T. initiate (vendor. af282.. 6SH37

AtL. t. buildPass (vendor. a7ff823... jis: 37)

At Object. e. apply (vendor. a7ff823... is: 370

At Object. e. trade (vendora7ff823--. js:37)

At Object. e. trade (vendor. a7ff823. - is:7)

At Object L. T. traverseAl1Pass (vendor. a7ff823.. 1s:37)

At C (vendor. a7ff823... 1s:37)

At Object. e.extender (yen or. a7ff823-js:32)

At Object. e. initialize (vendor. a7ff82. s: 37)`

1. By typing a log, it was determined that the code error occurred during the initialization phase of the vtkjs interactor. initialize(). Prior to this sentence, I used interface. setView (openGLrenderWindow) and interface. bindeEvents (container). I attempted to print out the openGLrenderWindow and container
2. Attempt to clear cache when closing and restarting the Electron application
3. Attempted to launch the application on computers with different performance, and found that the frequency of this bug appearing was lower on computers with higher performance
4. The issue did not occur on the Win10 system
5. The issue did not occur on the browser side